# Why does my css/js dropdown menu hide before reaching the end of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have a simple dropdown submenu that I show when you hover a list element of a horizontal menu.

I position the dropdown submenu by setting relative position to LI parent and absolute position to the container of the submenu.

Then I show the submenu by listening to mouseenter with jquery and I hide it by listening to mouseleave.

At first looks like everything is working fine, but after adding some content to the submenu so that it now has like 100px height I'm starting to have a problem:

The mouseenter runs fine but the mouseleave gets fired a lot before reaching the end of the submenu, it gets fired when I'm half a way to reach the end.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question even if I did not provide code examples, I just want to explain the situation and what was going on.

Looks like the content I had after my main horizontal menu, had a default z-index that caused it to be placed on top of my dropdown.

So what was happening is that when I was going down with my cursor when I reached the content after my horizontal menu, even if I had not reached yet the end of my dropdown, I was somehow with my cursor off my dropdown because of the z-index.

So my solution was to test with some z-index added to the dropdown, such as z-index: 11, and it worked! The z-index you should set in your case could vary depending on what positioning and z-index has other content on your page.

Hope it helps someone!